# Is it possible to generate md-option elements dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a web application where I use `<md-select>` elements from angular-material. The option values are provided by a service like this:

```
<md-option *ngFor="let option of settingsService.getOption(name)" [value]="option.description">
    {{option.description}}
</md-option>
```

Only the 'name' varibale is changing on different forms so I should have to copy this code snippet everywhere in my application. I would like to create a reusable component or directive which can generate this code snippet by a name. I tried to wrap the whole `<md-select>` into a custom control value accessor but in this case the inner form control (the control of the md-select) won't be notified about the validation changes. Is it possible to generate those options somehow, so that I could place the form control to the select element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **No, it won't work.**.

`md-select` works by querying `ContentChildren` which are instances of the `MdOption` component inside it as it's immediate children.
If you use a custom component:

```
@Component({
    select: 'foo-options',
    template: `
        <md-option value="some">Some Value</md-option>
    `
})
class AutoCompileOptionsComponent {}
```

And then use like:

```
<md-select>
    <foo-options></foo-options>
</md-select>
```

When doing it this way, `md-select` will not "see" the `md-option` components as it's `ContentChildren` because it expects the immediate child components inside it to be an instance of `MdOption`.

Strangely, when not using custom components, it does work:

```
<md-select>
    <div>
        <md-option value="hah">Hah</md-option>
    </div>
</md-select>
```

Comment: I expected for this answer. :/ I double checked the code of the md-select and I got the same conclusion you wrote above. I have to find another way, but thanks for the clarification. I will accept this answer.